# How to select all classNames of a page using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium (with java) to search all the classNames of a Page and then use Regex to only save the className(s) which have "insignia" in them.

I tried using the below code with regex to search for classNames which a mention of "insignia" in them but it didn't return any result.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.className(".*\\binsignia\\b.*")).get(1).getAttribute("src"));
```

Comment: You can't use regex inside a locator string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Regex inside a locator string. You can use a CSS selector and find all elements that contain "insignia" in the class name.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='insignia']")).get(1).getAttribute("src"));
```

[CSS selector reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'.*\\binsignia\\b.*')]")
```

is going to return the webElements containing class name `insignia`